# How to update data in SQL Server from Excel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel

I have uploaded an Excel sheet. I want to update the database when I will upload the same Excel sheet with different data. Should I use a stored procedure for that? How to proceed?

```
using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
{
    excel_con.Open();

    string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

    DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();

    //[OPTIONAL]: It is recommended as otherwise the data will be considered as String by default.
    dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("PersonId", typeof(int)), new DataColumn("Name", typeof(int)), new DataColumn("Salary",typeof(decimal)) });

    using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "A7:B]", excel_con))
    {
        oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
    }

    excel_con.Close();

    string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
    {
        using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
        {
            // Set the database table name
            sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.tblPerson";

            //[OPTIONAL]: Map the Excel columns with that of the database table
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("PersonId", "PersonId");
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Salary", "Salary");

            con.Open();
            sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: whats wrong with bulk copy when data has been changed. For this scenario bulk copy is ok i guess but you have to take measure so that duplicate record won't get saved.

Comment: Assuming there's no data in the table that you need to save, you just delete the table contents and reload it. If you do need to save data, then you need to work out a key in the data that lets you recognise when rows match.